# Utilizar {{ asset() }} en un echo

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Necesito hacer una consulta de imagenes guardadas en el servidor para mostrarlas en una vista

```
 echo "<img src={{asset ('images/producto/{$producto->imagen}'}} title='{$producto->imagen}'/>";
```

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que no funciona o que es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: hola @Shaz  
'src={{asset ('images/producto/{$producto->imagen}'}}' no me permite cargar la una imagen no se interpreta en el navegador  esto por usar a lo que entiendo se genera un conflicto por el echo

Comment: De esta manera logro cargar la imagen correctamente

Comment: `echo "<img class='imagen responsive' src='../images/producto/{$producto->imagen}' title='{$producto->imagen}'/>";`

Comment: Hola @harriroot !, podrías editar tu pregunta con la aclaración que haces en el comentario? así todos los usuarios que la lean vean directamente lo que te está pasando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hace Blade en este caso no es más que una especie de echo, por ende sería redundante lo que estás haciendo (echo dentro de otro echo), algo así debería funcionar:

```
<img src={{ asset('images/producto/' . $producto->imagen) }} title='{{ $producto->imagen }}' />
```

Asumo que estás en una vista de blade para lo cual utilizo el estilo PHP en HTML (y no al revés como lo estabas haciendo).

Comment: entiendo  la redundancia

Comment: existe alguna manera de implementar ***asset*** dentro de <?php  ?> con un echo o print?

Comment: `<?php echo asset(....) ?>`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Shaz me fue util para hacer esto
`echo "<img class='imagen responsive' src='".asset('images/producto/'.$producto->imagen)."' title='$producto->imagen'/>";
`

Comment: Si fue útil la respuesta, podrías considerar marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

primero hay que ejecutar en el terminal `php artisan storage:link` y luego utilizar `asset()`, para que se vincule la carpeta storage con las rutas y no haya que utilizar `../`, eso si, concatenar el respectivo `'/'` cuando se muestra por pantalla